# Que veut dire l'expression « Blaireau, va! »?

Tags: sens, insultes

Que veut dire l'expression « Blaireau, va! »? Est-ce lié à la bande dessinée *Parker & Badger*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En langage militaire, un blaireau désignait un bleu (une jeune recrue, à cause de leur uniforme bleu), puis par extension une personne insignifiante, ridicule. C'est donc une insulte, comme un *naze*, un *nul*.

Ensuite, l'interjection *va !* exprime ici le dédain. Il est très courant de construire des phrases de ce type avec une insulte + va !

C'est donc une phrase équivalente à « espèce de nul ! ».